# How do I get authorization to work in Azure like it does in a .NET web app?

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-web-app-service

In my .NET web app, if I want to only allow certain people and groups access to it all I have to do in my web.config is:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Blessed" />
    <allow roles="Anointed" />
    <allow users="domainname\gifteduser" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

publish to IIS and I'm done. But that doesn't seem to work on Azure when I publish my web app there.

So how does one setup Azure to get the same functionality/restrictions?

Comment: Take a look at [Azure Active Directory quickstart](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/)

Comment: So no one has ever had to do this or convert a .NET app to Azure to provide this same functionality?